# sp_help_revlogin causing loss of characters on LOGINs with Unicode characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to export all users of SQL Server and I found following stored procedure from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances) but when I Ran the Procedure, the results of some names just exported as ??????. For example:

```
-- Login: ??????
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'??????')
                  BEGIN
CREATE LOGIN [??????] WITH PASSWORD = 0x0200B27F654A0090DFA7C3C857709164CDC91F1 HASHED, SID = 0x27926CE54FA0E64BB2300AE2E104C22C, DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english], CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF

    EXEC master.dbo.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame='?????', @rolename='sysadmin'
END
```

All of Unicode users was shown as ?????? . the SP is as follow:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_help_revlogin]   
  (
      @login_name sysname = NULL 
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @name                     SYSNAME
      DECLARE @type                     VARCHAR (1)
      DECLARE @hasaccess                INT
      DECLARE @denylogin                INT
      DECLARE @is_disabled              INT
      DECLARE @PWD_varbinary            VARBINARY (256)
      DECLARE @PWD_string               VARCHAR (514)
      DECLARE @SID_varbinary            VARBINARY (85)
      DECLARE @SID_string               VARCHAR (514)
      DECLARE @tmpstr                   VARCHAR (1024)
      DECLARE @is_policy_checked        VARCHAR (3)
      DECLARE @is_expiration_checked    VARCHAR (3)
      Declare @Prefix                   VARCHAR(255)
      DECLARE @defaultdb                SYSNAME
      DECLARE @defaultlanguage          SYSNAME     
      DECLARE @tmpstrRole               VARCHAR (1024)

  IF (@login_name IS NULL)
  BEGIN
      DECLARE login_curs CURSOR 
      FOR 
          SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin, p.default_language_name  
          FROM  sys.server_principals p 
          LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins     l ON ( l.name = p.name ) 
          WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) 
            AND p.name <> 'sa'
          ORDER BY p.name
  END
  ELSE
          DECLARE login_curs CURSOR 
          FOR 
              SELECT p.sid, p.name, p.type, p.is_disabled, p.default_database_name, l.hasaccess, l.denylogin, p.default_language_name  
              FROM  sys.server_principals p 
              LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins        l ON ( l.name = p.name ) 
              WHERE p.type IN ( 'S', 'G', 'U' ) 
                AND p.name = @login_name
              ORDER BY p.name

          OPEN login_curs 
          FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin, @defaultlanguage 
          IF (@@fetch_status = -1)
          BEGIN
                PRINT 'No login(s) found.'
                CLOSE login_curs
                DEALLOCATE login_curs
                RETURN -1
          END

          SET @tmpstr = '/* sp_help_revlogin script '
          PRINT @tmpstr

          SET @tmpstr = '** Generated ' + CONVERT (varchar, GETDATE()) + ' on ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' */'

          PRINT @tmpstr
          PRINT ''

          WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
          BEGIN
            IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
            BEGIN
                  PRINT ''

                  SET @tmpstr = '-- Login: ' + @name

                  PRINT @tmpstr

                  SET @tmpstr='IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'''+@name+''')
                  BEGIN'
                  Print @tmpstr 

                  IF (@type IN ( 'G', 'U'))
                  BEGIN -- NT authenticated account/group 
                    SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']'
                  END
                  ELSE 
                  BEGIN -- SQL Server authentication
                          -- obtain password and sid
                          SET @PWD_varbinary = CAST( LOGINPROPERTY( @name, 'PasswordHash' ) AS varbinary (256) )

                          EXEC sp_hexadecimal @PWD_varbinary, @PWD_string OUT
                          EXEC sp_hexadecimal @SID_varbinary,@SID_string OUT

                          -- obtain password policy state
                          SELECT @is_policy_checked     = CASE is_policy_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END 
                          FROM sys.sql_logins 
                          WHERE name = @name

                          SELECT @is_expiration_checked = CASE is_expiration_checked WHEN 1 THEN 'ON' WHEN 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE NULL END 
                          FROM sys.sql_logins 
                          WHERE name = @name

                          SET @tmpstr = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + @PWD_string + ' HASHED, SID = ' 
                                          + @SID_string + ', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [' + @defaultdb + ']' + ', DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [' + @defaultlanguage + ']'

                          IF ( @is_policy_checked IS NOT NULL )
                          BEGIN
                            SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_POLICY = ' + @is_policy_checked
                          END

                          IF ( @is_expiration_checked IS NOT NULL )
                          BEGIN
                            SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + ', CHECK_EXPIRATION = ' + @is_expiration_checked
                          END
          END

          IF (@denylogin = 1)
          BEGIN -- login is denied access
              SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; DENY CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
          END
          ELSE IF (@hasaccess = 0)
          BEGIN -- login exists but does not have access
              SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; REVOKE CONNECT SQL TO ' + QUOTENAME( @name )
          END
          IF (@is_disabled = 1)
          BEGIN -- login is disabled
              SET @tmpstr = @tmpstr + '; ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME( @name ) + ' DISABLE'
          END 

          SET @Prefix = '
          EXEC master.dbo.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame='''

          SET @tmpstrRole=''

          SELECT @tmpstrRole = @tmpstrRole
              + CASE WHEN sysadmin        = 1 THEN @Prefix + [LoginName] + ''', @rolename=''sysadmin'''        ELSE '' END
              + CASE WHEN securityadmin   = 1 THEN @Prefix + [LoginName] + ''', @rolename=''securityadmin'''   ELSE '' END
              + CASE WHEN serveradmin     = 1 THEN @Prefix + [LoginName] + ''', @rolename=''serveradmin'''     ELSE '' END
              + CASE WHEN setupadmin      = 1 THEN @Prefix + [LoginName] + ''', @rolename=''setupadmin'''      ELSE '' END
              + CASE WHEN processadmin    = 1 THEN @Prefix + [LoginName] + ''', @rolename=''processadmin'''    ELSE '' END
              + CASE WHEN diskadmin       = 1 THEN @Prefix + [LoginName] + ''', @rolename=''diskadmin'''       ELSE '' END
              + CASE WHEN dbcreator       = 1 THEN @Prefix + [LoginName] + ''', @rolename=''dbcreator'''       ELSE '' END
              + CASE WHEN bulkadmin       = 1 THEN @Prefix + [LoginName] + ''', @rolename=''bulkadmin'''       ELSE '' END
            FROM (
                      SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),SUSER_SNAME(sid)) AS [LoginName],
                              sysadmin,
                              securityadmin,
                              serveradmin,
                              setupadmin,
                              processadmin,
                              diskadmin,
                              dbcreator,
                              bulkadmin
                      FROM sys.syslogins
                      WHERE (       sysadmin<>0
                              OR    securityadmin<>0
                              OR    serveradmin<>0
                              OR    setupadmin <>0
                              OR    processadmin <>0
                              OR    diskadmin<>0
                              OR    dbcreator<>0
                              OR    bulkadmin<>0
                          ) 
                          AND name=@name 
                ) L 
              PRINT @tmpstr
              PRINT @tmpstrRole
              PRINT 'END'
          END 
          FETCH NEXT FROM login_curs INTO @SID_varbinary, @name, @type, @is_disabled, @defaultdb, @hasaccess, @denylogin, @defaultlanguage 
      END
      CLOSE login_curs
      DEALLOCATE login_curs
      RETURN 0
  END
GO
```

The number of users registered in the system as Unicode is large and it takes a long time to transfer them manually. So I need a solution that I can use to display Unicode users correctly.

Comment: *"All of Unicode users was shown as ??????"* Sounds like, somewhere, you used a `varchar` instead of a `nvarchar` (or `sysname`).

Comment: Guessing you got it from this [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances)? Not going to lie, it's poorly written. Perhaps someone (or myself) will get around to making a pull request on it to improve it. Unfortunately it declared `@tmpstr` and `@tmpstrRole` as a `varchar`, meaning that any characters outside of the code page were lost. It does, however, make several other bad habits; such as not quoting injected values, and using the `sp_` prefix, and using `sp_addsrvrolemember` which has been deprecated for *years*.

Comment: In truth, if you change all the variables to be an `nvarchar` where they are a `varchar` you should get some better results. It still has problems, don't get me wrong, but you shouldn't suffer the character loss. I must admit, I find it really odd that they make such a trivial mistake (or just poorly assumed that `LOGIN` names won't include characters outside of the default code page).

Comment: I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/7207) for anyone interested in doing a PR.

Comment: Andy Mallon posted [an improved set of queries](https://am2.co/2021/07/dba-serverlogins/) for this to GitHub back in July.

Comment: @Larnu That code is an utter horror-show, it could have been written in about half the size in probably a single query. I'm surprised it made its way into an official KB, it looks like a My First TechNet Article to be honest.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that the thing won't be look at, @Charlieface, and hence why I'm tempted to do my own PR; but not right now.

Comment: @Larnu I guess I'm bored....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying that it's much better to do this via some tool, rather than cobbling together something in T-SQL. You can use SSMS or similar.

Be that as it may:

The script you have posted has multiple issues.

- **The primary issue you were facing:** use of `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`, means that other languages get clobbered.
- Use of a cursor unnecessarily. This can be done in a single query using string aggregation.
- The binary-to-hex procedure is complete overkill, as this can be done with a simple `CONVERT`. Even if it were necessary, it could have been done with an inline TVF.
- Some missing `QUOTENAME` usages, to quote the names correctly.
- It only adds fixed server roles, rather than any user-defined roles
- It only adds `CONNECT` permissions, rather than any other permissions.
- Usage of the deprecated `sys.syslogins`, which was replaced in 2005.

**The following script is a full rewrite.**

- It returns all SQL logins and Windows logins based on AD users or AD groups (but not any other logins such as certificate based ones).
- It adds all *server*-level permissions.
- It adds all server roles, including user-defined.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_help_revlogin]   
      @login_name sysname = NULL 
AS

SELECT
    '
/* sp_help_revlogin script
** Generated ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE()) + ' on ' + QUOTENAME(@@SERVERNAME) + ' */
GO
' + STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
    '
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N',
    QUOTENAME(p.name, ''''),
    ')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN ',
    QUOTENAME(p.name),
    CASE WHEN p.type IN ('G', 'U') THEN ' FROM WINDOWS' END,
    ' WITH',
    CASE WHEN p.type = 'S' THEN CONCAT(
        ' PASSWORD = ',
        CONVERT(nvarchar(max), ISNULL(l.password_hash, 0x0), 1),
        ' HASHED, SID = ',
        CONVERT(nvarchar(max), p.sid, 1),
        CASE WHEN l.is_policy_checked = 0 THEN ', CHECK_POLICY = OFF' END,
        CASE WHEN l.is_expiration_checked = 1 THEN ', CHECK_EXPIRATION = ON' END,
        ','
      ) END,
    ' DEFAULT_DATABASE = ',
    QUOTENAME(p.default_database_name),
    ', DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = ',
    QUOTENAME(p.default_language_name),
    ';
END;
GO
',
    CASE WHEN p.is_disabled = 1 THEN
      'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(p.name) + ' DISABLE;
GO
'
      END,
    r.roles + '
GO
',
    sp.perms + '
GO
'
    ), N'
') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.name)

FROM sys.server_principals p
LEFT JOIN sys.sql_logins l ON l.principal_id = p.principal_id

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(

        'EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = ' + p2.name + ', @rolename = ' + QUOTENAME(r.name, '''') + ';'
      , '
GO
'
    )
    FROM sys.server_role_members rm
    JOIN sys.server_principals r ON r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES( QUOTENAME(p.name, '''') )) p2(name)  -- error 8124 
    WHERE rm.member_principal_id = p.principal_id
) r(roles)

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(

        CASE WHEN sp.state = 'W' THEN N'GRANT' ELSE sp.state_desc END,
        ' ',
        sp.permission_name  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT,
        ' TO ',
        p2.name,
        CASE WHEN sp.state = 'W' THEN N' WITH GRANT OPTION' END,
        ';'
      ), N'
GO
'
    )
    FROM sys.server_permissions sp
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES( QUOTENAME(p.name, '''') )) p2(name)  -- error 8124 
    WHERE sp.grantee_principal_id = p.principal_id
      AND sp.class = 100
) sp(perms)

WHERE p.type IN ('S', 'G', 'U')
  AND p.name <> 'sa'
  AND (p.name = @login_name OR @login_name IS NULL);

GO
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05b300afdd5b632524bd7399b0271d16)