# Copy existing AD account for SQL access with all rights and else to a new AD user

Tags: sql-server, user-controls, transfer, rights

I have to set an old AD user to a new ad user.

The old AD user has many access rights on several databases, tables, roles ....whatever.

I must create a new user, already set in the AD and give them the same rights back, as the old AD account had.

I made this manually, but I have a lot of trouble with this doing/thinking.

If I thought, I have all set, then I found on access from the application, used by a DSN ODVC resource from another system, that I have overseen alter rights in tables or no access on functions and so on.

How I can get all old permissions, settings from several databases from one user - to keep this settings to  the same database on the new AD user account?
the permissions are not set on the AD for the users.

Comment: Possibly relevant: a rewrite of `sp_help_revlogin` https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779202/14868997 you need to modify that to get database-level permissions from multiple databases

Comment: @Charlieface If you're interested, it might be worth submitting the improved version to Microsoft: there's an [open issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/7207#issuecomment-1487582242) on the matter at the moment.

Comment: @ThomA Might do when I get a chance.